# Is this DIY pull up bar and dips station structurally sound and is it a good solution?

Tags: pipe

The gyms in my area are closed. I am renting a house, so I can't permanently attach anything to my residence. My back yard is small and lacks trees of any size or any secure mounting points.

So, I'd like to design something to work out with during the lock down that doesn't break the bank since I may be on the bubble for getting laid off in the next few months if the economy doesn't turn around. And, ya, I realize I can do body weight work outs and resistance bands and so on (which I've been doing). But something like the attached picture would be very helpful.

Please let me know if this design is structurally sound for pull ups and dips. It uses 1.25" galvanized pipe and kee (or similar) clamps. I need this to be able to be disassembled and moved when I eventually move out of this rental and/or am able to go back to the gym so wood is probably out of the question. And very importantly, I need to minimize the cost.

[image]

[image]

3rd iteration adding additional diagonal supports:
[image]

Comment: You may need a couple of corner brackets on the tall section but I don’t see why it would not work, with the base extended it won’t tip over but I would be concerned about side to side forces.

Comment: Thanks so much! I added a couple of corners for the lateral loads. Would that be sufficient to make this thing structurally sound enough to be able to work out on?

Comment: Also consider lateral loads in the other direction as well.

Comment: Thank you to all. I added a third iteration of the design with additional diagonal supports. Please let me know if this would be sufficient to hold up to a work out.

Answer (score 3):

This is not as structurally sound as it could/should be. With such large dimensions between corners, adding some diagonal bracing will improve the strength by a substantial margin. As I typed this, I see Ed Beal has added the equivalent in a comment.

Triangles are your friends.

Comment: Thank you! Please take a look at my second picture that I added to the post with diagonal bracing for the lateral loads. Would that make this thing structurally sound enough to work out on?

Answer (score 0):

Both drawings are not strong enough. The triangles you added in the second picture only reinforce in the side-to-side direction, you need to add triangle reinforcement to every rectangular plane you can foresee a force acting upon. Add another reinforcement perpendicular to the one added in the second picture, both forward and backward. Add triangle reinforcements on the dip station between the bottom pipes to add rigidity.

Comment: Please check out the third design iteration with additional diagonal supports. I'm trying to keep costs down. Each of the 45 deg clamps costs $15-$20. So the 45 deg clamps alone on the most recent design total up to about $250 to $300. I'm trying to get away with as minimal of a design as possible.

Comment: Reinforce thoroughly and keep the cost down by building the frame out of lumber.

Comment: @Poe try to keep your costs down by staying out of hospital!